# Зачем нужен метод .keys()?

Tags: python

Ведь если мы обращаемся просто к словарю без этого метода, то вроде получаем один и тот же результат. Получается он совсем бесполезен, или у него есть какое-то конкретное значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция keys() нужна, чтобы получить только ключи словаря:

```
>>> d = {1:2,3:4,5:6}
>>> print(d.keys())
dict_keys([1, 3, 5])
```

Если обраться к словарю просто так, то получим весь словарь:

```
>>> print(d)
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

Как видим, результат совсем не один и тот же.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо.